# Drag and drop the layout using button

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag linear_layout_mouse as given in XML below. I want to drag the entire layout using middle button given in the layout.
    I am able to drag the layout but when I am dropping it, layout gets vanished.
    In logcat, When dropped I am getting log as "Reporting drop result: false".
I have used DragShadowBuilder for this.

```
Can anyone help me out to fix this problem.?


Code:

// On touch listener

oMiddleButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(mouseLayout); 
                    mouseLayout.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, mouseLayout, 0); 
                    mouseLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                    return true;
                  } 
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

oMiddleButton.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    System.out.println("Drag event started");
                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    System.out.println("Drag event entered into "+mouseLayout.toString());
                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    System.out.println("Drag event exited from "+mouseLayout.toString());
                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                System.out.println("Dropped");
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                  ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                  owner.removeView(view);
                 RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_shared_screen);
                  container.removeView(view);
                  container.addView(mouseLayout);
                  mouseLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    System.out.println("Drag ended");
                  break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    mouseLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                default:
                  break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

// XML Layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/relative_layout_shared_screen"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_shared_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/temp" />

        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_mouse"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/mouse_controller" >

        <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/left_panel_container"
                android:layout_width="33dp" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/left_top_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"    
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/left_bottom_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"    
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/middle_panel_container"
            android:layout_width="33dp" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical">
                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/middle_top_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="27dp" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/middle_middle_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="9dp" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/middle_bottom_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

         </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/right_panel_container"
                android:layout_width="33dp" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/right_top_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="33dp" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/right_bottom_button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="27dp" 
                    android:background="#07000000"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```